# Is the set $C = \left\{ (x, y, z) \in \mathbb R^3 : y^2+z^2 = 1, xz =3 \right\}$ compact?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-curves

Is the following set compact? How can I show it?

$$C = \left\{ (x, y, z) \in \mathbb R^3 : y^2+z^2 = 1, xz =3 \right\}$$

Clearly it is closed as it contains its boundary, but I can not show that it is bounded..

Comment: It is not bounded. Take any $x$, $|x|>3$ and you can then calculate $z=3/x, |z|<1$ and then $y=\pm\sqrt{1-z^2}$ thus obtaining a point $(x,y,z)\in C$. As the range of $x$ is unbounded, so is the set $C$.

Comment: Thank you.......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not compact, as it is not bounded.
Let $A:=\{z\in(-1,0)\cup(0,1)\vert (3/z,\sqrt{1-z^2},z)\}$ be an unbounded set contained in $C$.

Comment: Surely $z\in(-1,0)\cup(0,1)$ ?

Comment: @StinkingBishop Yes, thank you very much. Very stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It is not bounded, so not compact, by Heine-Borel.   Look at $y^2+9/x^2=1$.  Here $x$ is free to roam (away from $(-3,3)$).